# Help with understanding Normal distribution problem $N(0,1)$ for $Y = X^2$

Tags: probability, statistics

LEt $X$ be normally distributed $N(0,1)$, find distribution of $Y = X^2$.

I already have the solution, I just don't understand it very well:

$$F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(x^2 \leq y) \ = P(-\sqrt{y}  \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}) = F_X(\sqrt{y})-F_X(-\sqrt{y}) $$

Here is the first thing that I don't understand, how to deal with that double inequality to get the desired result.

$$F_Y(y) = F_X(\sqrt{y})-F_X(-\sqrt{y})$$

$$P_Y(y) = p_x\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}-p_x(-\sqrt{y})(\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{y}})$$

I also don't understand how we got from $F_Y$ to $P_Y$

Comment: That's just the chain rule. Remember the derivative of the CDF $F(y)$ is the pdf $f(y)$ (in your case $P(y)$). However, in the argument, instead of $"y"$ you have $"\sqrt{y}"$ so you have to use the chain rule to differentiate correctly.

Comment: @ VLC Also, in case you are interested, $Y$ is just chi square with one degree of freedom

Answer (score 1):

Y = X²
So in real variable, y = x², thus x = ±y
F(y) = P(Y≤y) = P( X² ≤ y)
= P(-√y ≤ X ≤ √y) = Fx(√y) - Fx(-√y)

p.d.f of y  = F' (y)
Also, pdf of x = F'(x)
Thus,
F'(y) = Fx' (√y) - Fx' (-√y)

pdf of y = (1/2√y) [ pdf of x = √y] - (-1/2√y) [ pdf of x = -√y]

```
    = 1/2√y [ {pdf of x = √y }+ {pdf of x = -√y} ]
```